# How to exit from videotest in the grub?

Tags: virtualbox, grub2

I am checking different video resolutions in the grub menu by using `videotest` and `vbetest` programs and can't go back to the `grub` command line, after using this programs. System doesn't respond - like hanging. Only Virtualbox's "poweroff the machine" helps.

**Question:** How exit from this mode? May be I use this programs wrong way?

**My actions:**

1. Enters to the grub menu, while booting, then go to the command mode.
2. Run `videotest 800x600` 
    [image: List item]
3. Look at the new resolution example 
    [image: List item]
4. Then, after pressing any key, system stops respond and I can't go back to the grub menu. Get this screen: 
   [image]

Comment: Did you do anything special to make this command available in grub? I don't see it in grub2 on Fedora 38

Answer (score 0):

On a qemu virtual machine Ctrl-Alt-Del does it (also `sendkey ctrl-alt-delete` in the qemu monitor; but on my machine I can simply type Ctrl-Alt-Del -- they're not special in my "desktop environment").

I'm not using virtualbox, but google says that virtualbox has a menu option ([Input->Keyboard->Insert Ctrl-Alt-Del](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799411/10306503))